# When trying to knit in RStudio it writes a ligature in the tex file and cannot compile it

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I'm working on a brand new install of Linux Mint (19.2), a brand new install of RStudio, and a brand new install of texlive.

---

When I try to knit an Rmarkdown file in RStudio I get the error

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ﬁ (U+FB01)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

It seems to be producing a ligature for the characters "fi" and the LaTeX is not able to read this.  However, I don't know how to make it stop producing this ligature.  I tried looking for other solutions and it led me to installing the newest version of texlive-full and running the `init-usertree`.  I tried then running `install tlmgr inputenc` and it returned an error.  I looked up the error, the recommendation was to set texlive to an earlier version.  Then I run it again and get

```
tlmgr install: package inputenc not present in repository.
```

Even if I chase this error down, it seems like I won't be solving my problem because this doesn't seem like it will fix the ligature issue.  I saw one recommendation to change the LaTeX typeset so I switched it from pdflatex to xelatex but that caused no change.

Comment: Interesting problem. Please narrow down you document to a [mre]. My guess is that you have a literal `ﬁ` in your code.

Comment: @RalfStubner After trying to run the tex file in TeXWorks the `fi` seems to first come in the code that comes in the preamble.  There are a lot of `\if` and `\fi` in the code that Knitr generates.  But I'll spend some time in a minute trying to pare it down to the first instance where it causes an issue.

Comment: A minimal tex file would also be interesting. However, producing a minimal Rmd file is probably easier/quicker.

Comment: @RalfStubner You were absolutely right, I didn't think about the possibility that my Rmd source could have a ligature because I typed it in RStudio ... but then I found one ... and I remembered that I had pasted some text from elsewhere.  So that was exactly the problem.  If you want to post the answer and collect some Stackoverflow points I'll accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation from Rmd to tex should not add an explicit `ﬁ` ligature. Therefore, it is most likely that your `Rmd` file already contains the ligature, probably as a result of a previous copy & paste.